# What happens if you leave security rules undefined in Firebase?

Tags: firebase

For example I define security rules for 5 nodes under my root, but not the 6th. If I just leave the 6th's rules blank, what does it default to?

Thanks!

Comment: If you will leave security rules blank then anyone can access that node without any authorization, which can be accessed either from web browser or any app.. so it's better to leave the default rule rather than deleting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you are talking about permissions that look like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "one": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null",
    },
    "two": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null",
    }
    ...
    "six": {
    }
  }
}
```

In the above set of rules, "one" and "two" will have authenticated read/write access, but "six" will not have any permission.

Child locations receive the same permissions that were granted to its parent.  An empty set of permissions do not change that fact.  An empty set of permissions is the same as no explicit permissions.

There is one primary rule that you need to keep in mind.  Once read/write access has been granted to a user at a location, all of its children will also have read/write from that same user. You cannot revoke permission after it has been granted.  If no read/write access has been granted, then users cannot access the location or any of its children.